# Access the motor power level

Tags: dji-sdk

I am trying to retrieve the current state of the motors (e.g. thrust percentage at each motor).  The only state information I can find is whether or not they are on.  Is it possible to get more detail about the current power setting?

Answer (score 0):

The motor power level / thrust percentage is not accessible using `DJI-SDK` at the moment. You can however read the `speed` (ground speed of the aircraft) and its `attitude`, if that is something that might work for your calculations.